# Check if dates on a list are older than 2 days

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime

i 've a list as below

```
list  = ['9/27/17', '9/26/17', '9/22/17']
```

And I would like to know how many dates are older than 2 days and how many older than 5 days (from today - current date). What's the best way to reach that? Note that sometimes the list has more dates, not just 3 as the example. Thanks in advance for your inputs/tips. Regrds.

Comment: Older than 2 days of.. _what_? Each other? From today?

Comment: An idea would be to include [date objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) in the list and calculate the differences based on [timedelta objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: Older than 2 days from current date (today).

Comment: Well.. Converting string to date, getting the current date and finding the difference between two dates are quite trivial and easy-to-find tasks. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code below

```
from datetime import datetime

def c(t):
    ttime = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%y')
  return ((datetime.now() - ttime).days)

timelist = ['9/27/17', '9/26/17', '9/22/17', '10/3/17']
timelist = [c(t) for t in timelist]
print(timelist)
```

it will return **[7, 8, 12, 1]** then you can do simple categorize it as you needs

basically you can parse anything using **strptime**, docs : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: great! will work on your suggestion.Generating a list will help me on next steps. thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

**This will work and gives the flexibility of changing your limit date range**

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

    #make a 2 day limit
    datelimit = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)

    yourlist  = ['9/27/17', '9/26/17', '9/22/17']

    for i in yourlist:
        j = datetime.strptime(i,  "%m/%d/%y")
        if j < datelimit:
            print (j.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

[image]